# What Happend after i Root my Android device? What effect will be on app and phone

Tags: android, permissions, system, root

Questions:

**1**. If in install app which uses system permission like `"android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"` than what this app will be automatically goes to **system folder**?

**2**. If i install app which not uses any system permission than what that app will also goes to system folder or it will install as normal application?.

Comment: this question about the android app permission and it strictly software question and permission related to root so it should not be off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you install app using the normal way, that is , use `adb install` or install from your device.

1. No, the app will be at /data/app
2. it will install as normal application

Root will not grant all app root privilege , nor change the install routine.

you can just take root as putting a `su` binary in your `/sbin`, thus your app can spawn processes as root, such as execute a shell command as root.

Comment: so after root any app will be grant this "android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" type of system permission?

Comment: no, "android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" is an android permission, root is getting linux root permission

Comment: ya i know that but i am asking after my device is root than i can use this "android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" permission in my app? and other app are using this same permission it will also worked?

Comment: hardly if you install your app. But you can try copy your apk to /system/app folder, may work, depends on how android framework verify this permission.